# Categories not updating

Tags: magento-1.9, category

I tried everything to make the categories get updated but it simply doesn't works. 
What I already did:

- Refresh Cache
- Refresh Indexes (admin and using shell/indexes.php)
- Check if the store was using the right root category
- Make sure that the categories are activated and anchor

The code that I'm using to load the categories is above:

```
<div class="home-side-menu-type2 hidden-xs hidden-sm hide side-categories side-block side-menu-type2" style="margin-bottom:20px;">
  <ul class="menu" align="left">
    <?php $helper = $this->helper('catalog/category') ?>
     <?php foreach ($helper->getStoreCategories() as $_category): ?>
     <li>
        <a href="<?php echo Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->setData($_category->getData())->getUrl(); ?>" title="<?php echo $_category->getName() ?>"><?php echo $_category->getName() ?></a>
     </li>
     <?php endforeach ?>
  </ul>
</div>
```

What I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

Your Code is perfect , Please just make sure that you does not have delete Default root Category (Category ID = 2 ) , and all other Categories are under Default Root Category...
wish it could help

Comment: I'm sure that this is ok: [categories](http://imgur.com/U4uzdQh) and [root](http://imgur.com/a/SsESS) :(

Comment: ok where did you use this code ? 
try with Mage::helper('catalog/category')  instead of $this->helper('catalog/category')

Comment: thanks but it didn't work :(